# python while loop still running after a condition is met

Tags: python, string, loops, while-loop, integer

I've been happily learning python over the last few days with today being much less happy. I isolated the below loop and its running even when the condition is met.

Any ideas as to why?

```
a = input("enter yes or no").lower


while a != "yes" or "no":
    a = input("Please enter a valid response: ").lower
```

I've tried `str(a)`.
I've tried removing the "or" and just having the one condition as "yes".
I've tried changing the != to == "yes" still didn't break out of the loop
I've copied the code to a new file and ran on its own
I've been running print statements at the beginning the make sure the code is saved when ran
I've tried ramming nails through my eye lids

At the point I feel like I must have some fundamental misunderstanding.

Comment: Your fundamental misunderstanding is how `or` works.

Comment: `a != "yes" or "no"` is always `True`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112125/how-to-test-multiple-variables-for-equality-against-a-single-value

Comment: Oh and setting `a` to a function instead of the function call result isn't going to help.

Comment: You have two errors: First, you need to *call* the function `lower` with this syntax: `lower()` instead of just `lower`.  Second, the "or" operator in Python evaluates each expression by itself, so you need to write the if statement as `if a !='yes' or a != 'no'`.  You should look through a basic Python tutorial to understand why.  Finally, I apologize for other StackOverflow users, who seem to prefer impressing one another with clever comments rather than helping a novice with a basic question.

Comment: @PaulCornelius thanks for apologizing on my behalf. Some questions just come up so often you can't help but be jaded.